# Receiving ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED after Sinatra deployment on Digital Ocean

Tags: postgresql, sinatra, web-deployment, digital-ocean

Having a problem with deployment of a small Sinatra app that works fine locally, and seems like its running on digital ocean, but can't be hit via the domain name. The following is the message I receive:

**This webpage is not available**

**Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

The following is what's displayed on my droplet using rackup -p 80, which to me indicates it should be able to be hit:

**Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)**

**Maximum connections set to 1024**

**Listening on localhost:80, CTRL+C to stop**

If it makes any difference, I also cannot hit the ip address directly. Anyone encounter similar problems or possibly a solution? The app is on ubuntu uses psql as a database. It would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Bind your app on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost:

`ruby your_app.rb -o 0.0.0.0`
or
`rackup --host 0.0.0.0`

In production, you should setup a reverse proxy (eg. using nginx or apache) to bind a domain to your app internal port insteal of opening everything on 0.0.0.0